# What is the default UID and PW for the printer Web Page on Canon Pixma iX6820? or how to reset it on Mac?

Tags: printer, canon-pixma

I have read through other posts on here and on Canon online support as well. I tried calling Canon for assistance and no one EVER answers, I'm in the merry-go-round of their VRU. I bought a Pixma iX6820 in June of 2020. I've never had a need to mess with any of the settings until recently when trying to adjust color vibrancy etc. on a photo. At which point, I realized that I cannot do that through the standard printer system dialog on my Mac. I have to go to the Printer Web Page/interface to view/make such adjustments. When I follow the instructions provided and go to the IP address for the printer, I am prompted with UID and PW which shows up as: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IulU8.png) when I add the pw per website/online help, it fails. Also, when I change to IP address and use id ADMIN and pw (Serial Number or canon) it fails. I'm really frustrated. Does someone on here know the answer??

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Canon support article](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART169302), to re-initialise the Pixma 6820 you press and hold the Cancel/Reset button until the power light flashes white 15 times; then release.

That should reset any passwords. To set a new password, see [this page](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART166685&cat=5026B&actp=LIST&showDraft=false).